# How to connect to iPage mysql database

Tags: mysql, datasource, weblogic12c

I am trying to create a data-source in my web-logic domain to remotely connect to ipage mysql database, but I don't know which driver to use, where is the host name and the port?? I have the database name and user name and password that I created in the ipage site.

Answer (score 1):

suppose your domin name is `abc.com` then your host should be `abccom`

```
$db= new mysqli("domaincom.ipagemysql.com","DB_user","password","DB_name");
if($db->connect_error)
{
    echo "ERROR: (".$db->connect_errno.") ".$db->connect_error;
    exit();
}
```

--------edited
to connectto mysql database you need to you need to have the following 4 things

```
1- host           //to access mysql DB at ipage use host=domain.ipagemysql.com (remember doamin without .com or .net see 1st line of my answer)
2- user           //you may know
3- password       //you may know
4- database_name  //you may know
```

I dont know the interface of webLogic how to input these.

Comment: I am using the weblogic view create datasource view, where to add this script ??

Comment: I don't know what kind of interface you are having, see edited portion of my answer, hopefully it will help you

Comment: It is really helpful but what about the port and the right mysql driver? , is is jdbc or jgt?

Comment: mysql uses 3306 as default port

Comment: How should I be storing these variables? Probably not as clear text in plain PHP files right?

Comment: if u have multiple domains then select default domain name then same as @alamnaryab instructions